# Xpath locator to chekboks

Tags: selenium, xpath

How to choose Xpath locator to checkbox using as a starting point the text "Step 1. Set the direction for self-development"?

[image]

For convenience, you can copy the text from here:

```
pdp-action-item-header__checkbox pdp-action-item-header__checkbox--unchecked

Step 1. Set the direction for self-development
```

I did this:

```
//div[@class='pdp-action-item-header__checkbox pdp-action-item-header__checkbox--unchecked']/descendant-or-self::div[text()='Step 1. Set the direction for self-development']
```

But it's not right

Comment: Please have a look at this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this xpath.

```
//div[text()(contains(.,'Step 1'))]/parent::/div[@class='pdp-action-item-header__checkbox pdp-action-item-header__checkbox--unchecked']
```

Comment: This does not fit. The text "STEP 1. ..." should be used as a starting point.

Comment: can you post the html instead of image.it is confusing

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I only have this image.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using xpath and multiple functions.

```
"//div[contains(text(), 'Step 1. Set the direction for self-development')]/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'pdp-action-item--goal')]//div[contains(@class, 'pdp-action-item-header__checkbox')]"
```

Let's break it down

1. We start from the desired text.

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Step 1. Set the direction for self-development')]
```

2. We look for its parent element. Common parent for text element and checkbox element. (Make sure I wrote the correct selector)

```
/ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'pdp-action-item--goal')]
```

3. Then we look for checkbox but in a context of common parent element

```
//div[contains(@class, 'pdp-action-item-header__checkbox')]
```

Comment: Do not use `contains(text(), 'String')` unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, it matches text based on partial input. To match exact input you can use `text()='myText'

Comment: No. It matches the first text node child. That's why is better to use the string value when you have mixed content (text and markup). Example: `//div[contains(., 'Step 1. Set the direction for self-development')]`

Comment: @Alejandro I disagree. It's better to use specific content. Just like we specify the tag to `div` and not use `*`.

Comment: It matches the first text node child. This won't be matched `<div>Step 1. Set the <em>direction</em> for self-development</div>`

Comment: @Alejandro It will match

Answer (score 0):

Try using this xpath:

```
 //div[text()='Step 1. Set the direction for self-development']/preceding::div[@class='pdp-action-item-header__checkbox pdp-action-item-header__checkbox--unchecked']
```